# Show Corresponding Value in an Object by Clicking an Item (HTML and Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, object, dom

I'm trying to make it so that clicking any item on my list would then return a value in another section, based on an object which I've defined. In this case, clicking the countryName should turn up infoNarrative in another section.

Here's as far as I've gotten so far (I'm an obvious beginner on HTML/Javascript and working through these problems is helpful for my learning). Please feel free to suggest any smarter suggestions, I'll be happy to learn other simple approaches too.

**HTML**

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="heading">
    <h1>Countries</h1>
  </div>
    <ul class="countryList">
    <li id = "afghanistan">Afghanistan</li>
    <li id = "bangladesh">Bangladesh</li>
    </ul>  
<div id="narrative" class="narrative">
    Narrative Should Turn Up Here</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
    'afghanistan': {
        countryName: 'Afghanistan',
        'infoNarrative': 'afg lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
        'link': 'google.com'
    },
    'bangladesh': {
        countryName: 'Bangladesh',
        'infoNarrative': 'bgd lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
        'link': 'google.com'
    }
    };
    
    
    document.getElementById("afghanistan").addEventListener("click", displayNarrative());
    
    function displayNarrative(testValue) {
        document.getElementById("narrative").innerHTML = countryData.testValue.infoNarrative;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the basic problem is that when you try to set the innerHTML, you need to use `countryData[testValue]` not `countryData.testValue`.  The first will look for a key which is the value of `testValue` variable.  The second will look for the "testValue" key which is not in your data set.

Also, you were invoking `displayNarrative` when you added the event listener instead of handing that thing a function that would get executed on the click.

Here's a working solution with a slight addition.  I added `class="countryItem"` to the html `li` tags so that you could easily select *all* items in the list and attach the event listener to them.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const countryData = {
    afghanistan: {
      countryName: "Afghanistan",
      infoNarrative: "afg lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
      link: "google.com"
    },
    bangladesh: {
      countryName: "Bangladesh",
      infoNarrative: "bgd lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
      link: "google.com"
    }
  };

  const items = document.getElementsByClassName('countryItem')
  Array.from(items).forEach(function(item) {
    item.addEventListener('click', function() {
      displayNarrative(item.id)
    })
  })

  function displayNarrative(countryKey) {
    const countryInfo = countryData[countryKey]
    document.getElementById("narrative").innerHTML =
      countryInfo.infoNarrative;
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="heading">
    <h1>Countries</h1>
  </div>
  <ul class="countryList">
    <li class="countryItem" id="afghanistan">Afghanistan</li>
    <li class="countryItem" id="bangladesh">Bangladesh</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="narrative" class="narrative">
    Narrative Should Turn Up Here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is excellent and works well, thanks so much! Is it also possible to shed some light on why the DOMContentLoaded must be used here?

Comment: You might not need it.  It depends where you are putting this code.  But as a good practice, you want to add your event listeners *after* all the dom is available on the page.  If you don't use that, depending on timing of the page and loading and such, it's possible the event listeners will properly get attached to the list items.  You can read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

Comment: Thanks a lot! And do you know where countryKey came from?

Comment: I named it `countryKey` as the input variable.  When you add the listener, we call `displayNarrative(item.id)` so for each item, the `id` attribute will be sent in to `displayNarrative` as the `countryKey`.